# Calculate AVG in a JOIN query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a join query in which I'm trying to calculate the average for one of the columns selected. This is my code:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID,'-',2) AS sampid, m.SUBJID, g.SMTS, m.SEX, m.DTHHRDY, g.SMMPPDUN 
-> FROM GTEX_Sample AS g 
-> JOIN GTEX_Pheno AS m ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID,'-',2)=m.SUBJID
-> WHERE m.SEX=2 
-> AND m.DTHHRDY=1 
-> AND g.SMTS='Blood';
```

Using this code i get this type of result:

```
+------------+------------+-------+------+---------+-----------+
| sampid     | SUBJID     | SMTS  | SEX  | DTHHRDY | SMMPPDUN  |
+------------+------------+-------+------+---------+-----------+
| GTEX-12ZZX | GTEX-12ZZX | Blood |    2 |       1 |         0 |
| GTEX-12ZZX | GTEX-12ZZX | Blood |    2 |       1 |  88055100 |
| GTEX-15ER7 | GTEX-15ER7 | Blood |    2 |       1 |         0 |
| GTEX-1F7RK | GTEX-1F7RK | Blood |    2 |       1 |         0 |
| GTEX-1F7RK | GTEX-1F7RK | Blood |    2 |       1 | 136881000 |
| GTEX-1GZHY | GTEX-1GZHY | Blood |    2 |       1 |         0 |
| GTEX-1GZHY | GTEX-1GZHY | Blood |    2 |       1 |  76308600 |
| GTEX-1PBJI | GTEX-1PBJI | Blood |    2 |       1 |         0 |
| GTEX-1PBJI | GTEX-1PBJI | Blood |    2 |       1 |  92091400 |
| GTEX-1POEN | GTEX-1POEN | Blood |    2 |       1 |         0 |
| GTEX-1POEN | GTEX-1POEN | Blood |    2 |       1 | 104267000
```

I want to calculate the average of the last column, i have used this code:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID,'-',2) AS sampid, m.SUBJID, g.SMTS, m.SEX, m.DTHHRDY, AVG(g.SMMPPDUN) AS result 
-> FROM GTEX_Sample AS g 
-> JOIN GTEX_Pheno AS m ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID,'-',2)=m.SUBJID 
-> WHERE m.SEX=2 
-> AND m.DTHHRDY=1 
-> AND g.SMTS='Blood'
```

And get the following error:

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression
> #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'catalogo.g.SAMPID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

In every way I try to add the AVG() function I get an error. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is unclear what you want to average.

Comment: And of course the error

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a `GROUP BY`.  That would suggest:

```
SELECT m.SUBJID, g.SMTS, m.SEX, m.DTHHRDY,
       AVG(g.SMMPPDUN) 
FROM GTEX_Sample g JOIN
     GTEX_Pheno m
     ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID, '-', 2) = m.SUBJID
WHERE m.SEX = 2 AND
      m.DTHHRDY = 1 AND
      g.SMTS = 'Blood'
GROUP BY m.SUBJID, g.SMTS, m.SEX, m.DTHHRDY;
```

Note that I removed the first `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` expression.  The `JOIN` condition means this is the same a `SUBJID`, so I see no reason to duplicate it.

This assumes that the five columns constitute a single group (row in the result set).

In you want the overall average but the individual rows, then use a window function:

```
SELECT . . .,  -- whatever columns you want
       AVG(g.SMMPPDUN) OVER () as overall_avg
FROM GTEX_Sample g JOIN
     GTEX_Pheno m
     ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID, '-', 2) = m.SUBJID
WHERE m.SEX = 2 AND
      m.DTHHRDY = 1 AND
      g.SMTS = 'Blood';
```

If you just want the average, then use an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AVG(g.SMMPPDUN) as overall_avg
FROM GTEX_Sample g JOIN
     GTEX_Pheno m
     ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.SAMPID, '-', 2) = m.SUBJID
WHERE m.SEX = 2 AND
      m.DTHHRDY = 1 AND
      g.SMTS = 'Blood';
```

Comment: But this way I get the average for each subject, I need the average for the entire column